Blazor Render Component Fails
I am rendering a Blazor component as follows:
private async Task PrintComponent()
{
    var htmlout = await BlazorRenderer.RenderComponent<BillView>();

    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("printComponent1", htmlout);
}

The BillView component is as follows:
<AuthorizeView Roles="Admin, Reception">
 <Authroized>
    <p> This is a bill.</p>
 </Authroized>
 <NotAuthorized>  
    <p>You are not authorized.</p>
 </NotAuthorized>

When I do not use the <AuthorizeView>, BillView renders and I can print.
When I use <AuthorizeView> I get this error on:
var htmlout = await BlazorRenderer.RenderComponent<BillView>();


System.InvalidOperationException: Authorization requires a cascading parameter of type Task. Consider using CascadingAuthenticationState to supply this. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(Int32 componentId, ParameterView initialParameters) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.BeginRenderingComponent(IComponent component, ParameterView initialParameters) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.HtmlRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView parameters) at BlazorRenderer.<>c__DisplayClass4_01.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\hp\source\repos\dajma00\Clinic\Clinic\Models\BlazorRenderer.cs:line 28 --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c__111.<b__11_0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Clinic.Pages.PatientOpen.PrintComponent() in C:\Users\hp\source\repos\dajma00\Clinic\Clinic\Pages\PatientOpen.razor:line 221 at

BlazorRenderer:
//from Andrew Lock. Makes it easy to use htmlRenderer. https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-rendering-blazor-components-to-a-string/
internal class BlazorRenderer
{
    private readonly HtmlRenderer _htmlRenderer;
    public BlazorRenderer(HtmlRenderer htmlRenderer)
    {
        _htmlRenderer = htmlRenderer;
    }

    // Renders a component T which doesn't require any parameters
    public Task<string> RenderComponent<T>() where T : IComponent
        => RenderComponent<T>(ParameterView.Empty);

    // Renders a component T using the provided dictionary of parameters
    public Task<string> RenderComponent<T>(Dictionary<string, object?> dictionary) where T : IComponent
        => RenderComponent<T>(ParameterView.FromDictionary(dictionary));

    private Task<string> RenderComponent<T>(ParameterView parameters) where T : IComponent
    {
        // Use the default dispatcher to invoke actions in the context of the 
        // static HTML renderer and return as a string
        return _htmlRenderer.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            HtmlRootComponent output = await _htmlRenderer.RenderComponentAsync<T>(parameters);
            return output.ToHtmlString();
        });
    }
}


Is BlazorRenderer is a wrapper around a HtmlRenderer?  If so where are you initializing it?  What IServiceProvider is it using?  My guess is that using using authentication isn't possible with the HtmlRenderer.  HtmlRenderer is not the fully blown Renderer used in the Blazor Hub.  It's a simplified version to allow you to render a component tree to a string.  You need to authenticate when or before you call PrintComponent.

Included the BlazorRenderer code.

I guessed as much.   Won't work.  You need to handle the authorization in where you call  PrintComponent.  A controller or minimal API definition?
